# PHP array_map() unable to parse csv data properly

Tags: php, csv

I am using PHP array_map function to parse a csv. This is my upload.php file:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($target_file));
    $arrlength = count($csv);
    for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++) {
      echo "<p><b>Customer # $row</b></p>";
      echo "<ul>";
      for ($col = 0; $col < 6; $col++) {
        echo "<li>".$csv[$row][$col]."</li>";

      }
      echo "</ul>";
    }
```

The output I am getting is like this:
[image]

Now I want to use all the values in Email Template Placeholders and send them individually to each and every client using email services like sendgrid/mailchimp.

But unfortunately, I am entirely stuck of how to move forward. I am not getting an idea of how can I parse all info for a particular customer, put them into email placeholders and then shoot them email.

**I know it's a very broad topic question, but a little help/guidance will be highly appreciated. **

Comment: In the loop itself, prepare an email template and send it to respective customer.